# How to fix gradle error in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to build an application for tracking the location as a background service. Latitude and Longitude points should change when the location changes.

The error I am getting is "failed linking references". So I tried changing the sdk version to 28 and build tools to 3.2.0 but facing issues.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.suppalapat21.tracker">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
 }
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.suppalapat21.tracker"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
           }
       }

 dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
 import android.content.IntentSender;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {


private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private double currentLatitude;
private double currentLongitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();


    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        
            .setFastestInterval(1000); 

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPause()");
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } else {

        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {

            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Error Message:

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
 Error:error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: check compileSdkVersion along with gradle version if it can't solve the problem, just delete .idea file and then sync project

Comment: I have changed the gradle version to 3.1.0 but it's not working. I even tried changing the compileSdkVersion to 28 and gradle to 3.2.0 but facing a different issue.